# How to fix a ModuleNotFoundError when packaging a Python app for PyPi

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pypi

I am getting this error when trying to run my app, downloaded from PyPi via

```
$ python3 -m pip install --user speed-reader
```

```
$ speed-reader --help
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/h5l/.local/bin/speed-reader", line 5, in <module>
    from reader import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'reader'
```

I've never packaged something for PyPi so I have  probably misunderstood their documentation.

Here is my setup.py

```
$ cat setup.py
import setuptools

with open("README.md", "r") as f:
    long_description = f.read()

setuptools.setup(
    name="speed-reader",
    version="1.0.3",
    author="h5law",
    author_email="h5law@pm.me",
    description="A speed reader implemented in Python",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="https://github.com/h5law/speed-reader",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent"
    ],
    python_requires='>=3.6',
    install_requires=["numpy", "click"],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'speed-reader = reader:main',
        ],
    },
)
```

Where am I going wrong? My directory structure is below:

```
reader/
 - LICENSE.txt
 - README.md
 - setup.py
 - requirements.txt
 - speed-reader/
    - __init__.py  [empty]
    - reader.py    [entry point main() exists]
```

The thing is that when run directly it works, so the problem must be with the packaging no?

```
$ python3 reader.py --help
Usage: reader.py [OPTIONS] PATH

Options:
  --version      Show the version and exit.
  --wpm INTEGER  Read at specified WPM, defaults to 160
  --help         Show this message and exit.
```

Update:

Installing the package like this

```
$ git clone https://github.com/h5law/speed-reader
$ cd speed-reader
$ python3 -m pip install .
```

Creates a fully working package where the error doesn't occur...

Any and all help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You're using `packages=setuptools.find_packages()`, this will find modules in the current directory.

A python module is either a `*.py` file or a directory with an `__init__.py` file in it.

Therefore `find_packages` is finding the `speed-reader` package only. If you wanted to access `reader.py` from within that, you would need to do:

```py
from speed_reader.reader import main
```